# 'Object.==' ('dynamic Function()') isn't a valid concrete implementation of 'Object.==' ('bool Function(dynamic)').dartinvalid_implementation_override

Tags: flutter, dart, class, object, oop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsteH.png)

'Object.==' ('dynamic Function()') isn't a valid concrete implementation of 'Object.==' ('bool Function(dynamic)').dartinvalid_implementation_override
i want to get a solve for this error th code runs normally but there is a error sign on class name why ?
this error in dart in vscode

this code is in dart

Answer (score 0):

[image: This is your code in my VSCode]

Checkout image above. My VSCode doesn't give any error. There's a problem with your VSCode, because the error said: `Object.==' ('dynamic Function()') isn't a valid concrete implementation...`. The operator `==` means "is equal to", and it doesn't exist in your code.

Well I write your code in [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev) also, and it also doesn't give any error. Tried to:

- Re-install Flutter
- Re-install VSCode's extensions
- If above steps don't help, re-install OS :)

Comment: but i tried a lot to solve and i thought the problem is from vscode i deleted it and downloaded it again and th problem still existing 
i will be grateful if you have any solve for it  Nguyen family

Comment: Well I write your code in https://dartpad.dev/ also, and it also doesn't give any error. Tried to:

Comment: My edit answer above

Comment: yeah i tried also to write it in dartpad and there is not error 
i don't know what i should make this is a terrible problem for me can you help me and iam sorry if i disturbed you

Comment: is there any chance that you named your project is "Animal"?

Comment: is there may work

Comment: can i chat with you to solve this problem if you don't mind
Nguyen family

Comment: yeah do you use telegram?

Comment: yes how could we chat there

Comment: oooooh finally i found the solve

Comment: oh great, how..?

Comment: Nguyen family 
i think i was foolish 
i deleted .vs code and error disappeared but in fact whn i downloaded dart extension again the error continued appearin 